# In a knot with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following domain object:

```
public class DomainObject<T,TRepo> 
  where T : DomainObject<T>
  where TRepo : IRepository<T>
{
      public static TRepo Repository { get;private set; }
}
```

#### A repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> //where T : DomainObject<T> // The catch 22
{
    void Save(T domainObject);
}
```

#### An implementation of the 2:

```
public class User : DomainObject<User,MyRepository>
{
    public string Name { get;private set;}
}

public class MyRepository : IRepository<User>
{
    public List<User> UsersWithNameBob()
    {

    }
}
```

So adding another method that isn't inside IRepository.

I want to enforce the repository as an IRepository while above it could be any type.

*A small sidenote:* I'm writing this for small systems with very few domain objects. I'm not looking to create anything that uses IoC, but rather something that is easy and simple to consume.

Thanks

Comment: Did you test that you actually *have* to cast User.Repository? Because you don't have to, it will be of type MyRepository and thus give access to UsersWithNameBob without changes to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, but something like this compiles:

```
public class DomainObject<T, TRepo> 
     where T: DomainObject<T, TRepo> 
     where TRepo: IRepository<T, TRepo>
{
     public static TRepo Repository
     {
         get;
         private set; 
     }
}

public interface IRepository<T, TRepo>
     where T: DomainObject<T, TRepo>
     where TRepo: IRepository<T, TRepo>
{
     void Save(T domainObject);
}
```

Comment: This was what I was after :) It feels a bit unnatural telling the interface that it is an IRepository, as it's implementing it

Comment: Well, you did the same thing already with the domain object ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of DomainObject is only specifying one generic type argument instead of two. Why isn't it:

```
public class User : DomainObject<User, MyRepository>
{
    public string Name { get;private set;}
}
```

If that doesn't work, could you explain in what way it doesn't do what you need?

Comment: That was an oversight, fixed it now

Comment: For the second point, I want to avoid casting to my custom Repository in order to access the additions it provides ontop of IRepository

Comment: Well I just tested it, and it all seems to work fine.  `DomainUser.Repository.UsersWithNameBob();` worked out A-OK.

Comment: You won't need to cast: `User.Repository` will be of type `MyRepository`.

Comment: agreed, I dont see the issue at all.

Comment: My explanation was confusing. I'll update it - what I meant was MyRepository<string> would work , Lucero's understood me somehow